# upsell.phtml in static block = Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object

Tags: php, error, product-list, static-block

I'll show my category list in a static block

```
<div>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="488" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</div>
```

No problem. But now I'm try to use the upsell.phtml- Template with

```
<div>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="488" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml"}}</div>
```

and I'll get these PHP Error. I'm not a PHP-developer, can you help me?

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object in /var/www/.../catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml on line 1
```

and there's the standard Magento Code (upsell.phtml)

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
```

I have no idea what's wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to only change the template, not the block type. If you check the block `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_list` you will see that there is no `getItemCollection` method on it, therefore this call will return null (or possibly an empty string, can't remember off the top of my head). This results in your template attempting to call `getItems` on that null/empty string. As @Keyul suggests the solution would be to use the block type that the upsell.phtml file is associated with, which is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_List_Upsell`. This block has the method `getItemCollection` and thus returns the collection expected in the template.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" category_id="488" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below one

{{block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" category_id="488" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml"}}